# Teams Bot Adaptive Card Fields show/hide on the basis of selection

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-design

I want to hide or show some fields in card depending upon the output of input.ChoiceSet. Could any please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Cards fields must be hide/visible on basis of input.ChoiceSet output.

Comment: Currently only this is available in adaptive card -https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ToggleVisibility.html. We will also check on the possibility of above issue.

Comment: Currently the above functionality is not supported. Using togglevisibility you can Toggle/Show/Hide a field.